# Creating PDF from html template in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I have a requirement that I need to create a PDF. For me the best way is to do it render html template and create a PDF with any third party lib. I have come across the solution which render HTML with ejs and create pdf with [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf). It works fine though but I had a problem with a page break.

There is a popular module [pdfkit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfkit). But it uses it own concept and procedure to render pdf. For node it does not render html file but for python it does render html template.

Please tell me how can i render html template to pdf using pdfKit and also what is the best way to render html and convert to pdf ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

[Puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) is the best way for converting HTML to the PDF, and also for web scraping.

A short instruction for generating PDF from HTML You can see [here](https://medium.com/@hardeek.sharma/converting-html-template-to-pdf-using-nodejs-2eff0247b50)
Also, the Chrome DevTools team maintains the library, so it is the best solution.
About the page-break. This issue can be solved in the HTML code. There is a style option for solving the issue.

```
style="page-break-after:always;"
```

Comment: Where page-break-after:always; goes?

Comment: @NingaCodingTRV 
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5277
could be helpful

Answer (score 2):

The problem with using PDF converter libraries available on NPM like pdfkit is that, you gonna have to recreate the page structures again in your html templates to get the desired output.

One of the best approach to rendering html and convert to pdf is by using [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) on NodeJs. Puppeteer is a Node library which provides a high-level API to control Chrome or Chromium over the DevTools Protocol. It can be used to generate screenshots and PDFs of html pages in your case.

Comment: The problem with Puppeteer  is, you can't show PDF previews in real time, but if you use  pdfkit, you can show preview. Anyway this decision based on the use case. 

I am having so much problem due to PDF preview. :(